# How can I get swiper to remember the last search I ran?

Tags: search, swiper

Sometimes I do a search with [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) and navigate to a location in the code that seems like what I was searching for, only to find it wasn't. This is more common with a symbol name that is a little too generic.

I'd like to simply restart the search, but I have to type the full symbol again.

I could copy/yank the symbol, which would be fine, but even that could be automated, as in: "search for thing under point." I'd probably want that too, but first thing: I'd just like to repeat the previous search.

How can I do that without having to re-type the criteria?  Or have swiper remember the last search?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you, are you meaning `M-p` ?

Comment: Actually this will work.  I was expecting the call to launch swiper and pre-populate the search.  This works just as well: start-search then iterate through the search history with `M-p`.

Comment: `C-s` after calling swiper - without input - will bring the last item in history too.

Comment: swiper is an isearch replacement and works on the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-s` after calling swiper will bring up the last search.
`M-p` will iterate back through the search history. `M-n` will do the same the other way.

If you followed the installation instructions and used the proposed bindings, `swiper-isearch` is bound to `C-s`, so `C-s C-s` will do what you want with zero effort.

As @NickD pointed, Swiper is an isearch replacement, most you did using isearch, will work with swiper.

On the secondary question, searching for "*thing at point*", you can choose between:

- using `C-s M-j` (assuming that `C-s` calls swiper), it'll insert the current subword in the minibuffer.
- writing a custom function which is basically a matter of using `thing-at-point` over what you find more useful, putting it into the completion list then `funcall` swiper or the other commands.

  `Swiper`'s author [provided the example code here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1068#issuecomment-318124861)

Finally, reading [the docs](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-that-alter-the-minibuffer-input) always worth the time spent doing it, usually saves unnecesary headaches.